# ¿Cómo crear carpetas y subcarpetas con una macro de Excel?

Tags: excel, macros

Me podrian apoyar por favor con el codgo de VB para excel con la finalidad de crear carpetas y subcarpetas, el requerimiento es el siguiente:

- El usuario debera ingresar el folio en el campo A2, dicho campo sera el nombre de la carpeta madre.
- El usuario debera ingresar datos en el rango de celdas B2:BN (La cantidad de campos es variable). Cada uno de estos campos debera ser una subcarpeta dentro de la carpeta madre.

Tengo este codigo que es el que me resuelve el segundo punto. Pero no he logrado crear el codigo que genere la carpeta madre y despues las subcarpetas:

```
Dim Ruta As String
Dim Fila, FilaFinal As Long

Ruta = "C:\Users\jmuro\Sync\Fotos"

FilaFinal = Application.CountA(Range("B:B"))

For Fila = 2 To FilaFinal
MkDir Ruta & "\" & Cells(Fila, 2)
Next Fila

MsgBox ("Se crearon las carpetas con exito")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CrearCarpetas()
    Dim Ruta As String
    Dim Fila, FilaFinal As Long
    
    ' Obtener el nombre de la carpeta madre ingresado por el usuario
    Dim CarpetaMadre As String
    CarpetaMadre = Range("A2").Value
    
    ' Verificar si se ingresó un nombre para la carpeta madre
    If CarpetaMadre = "" Then
        MsgBox "Por favor, ingrese un nombre para la carpeta madre en la celda A2."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Crear la carpeta madre
    Ruta = "C:\Users\jmuro\Sync\Fotos\" & CarpetaMadre
    MkDir Ruta
    
    ' Obtener la última columna con datos en la fila 2
    FilaFinal = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ' Crear las subcarpetas
    For Fila = 2 To FilaFinal
        MkDir Ruta & "\" & Cells(2, Fila).Value
    Next Fila
    
    MsgBox "Se crearon las carpetas con éxito."
End Sub
```

primero verifica si se ingresó un nombre para la carpeta madre en la celda A2. Si no se ingresó ningún nombre, muestra un mensaje de error y finaliza el código. Luego, crea la carpeta madre utilizando el nombre ingresado por el usuario. A continuación, recorre las celdas desde B2 hasta la última columna con datos en la fila 2, y crea una subcarpeta para cada valor ingresado.

Comment: Gracias buen hombre, funciona de maravilla.